# How to check if value already exists in javascript JSON array?

Tags: javascript, twitch

```
var ComfyJS = require("comfy.js");
var fs = require('fs');

const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('database.json');
const dataJSON = dataBuffer.toString();
const scoreBoard = JSON.parse(dataJSON);

ComfyJS.onChat = (user, message, flags, self, extra) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < scoreBoard.length; i++) {
      if (scoreBoard[i].name == user) {
        console.log('The name already exist');
      }
      else{
        scoreBoard.push({name:user,score:message});
      }
    }

    var data = JSON.stringify(scoreBoard);

    fs.writeFile('database.json', data, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There has been an error saving your configuration data.');
        console.log(err.message);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Configuration saved successfully.')
    });
}
```

Hi I'm new to code and I'd like to build a twitch bot and I want to save my data on a JSON file. ComfyJS.onchat triggers when somebody types something on chat and I want to take their name and message(score) as value and save it on my database but I need to save them one by one so if the name already exists in JSON file I don't want to add it. How should I fix it?

Comment: The only JSON in your script is in `dataJSON` and `data`. None of these variables are modified, hence this is not a JSON topic. `scoreBoard` is an array of objects.

Comment: [mcve] -> _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ComfyJS.onChat = (user, message, flags, self, extra) => {
  const exists = scoreBoard.find(fn => fn.name === user)
  if (exists) return;
  scoreBoard.push({
    name: user,
    score: message
  });

  var data = JSON.stringify(scoreBoard);

  fs.writeFile('database.json', data, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('There has been an error saving your configuration data.');
      console.log(err.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Configuration saved successfully.')
  });
}
```